# Did volume control just mess up my volume buttons?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, speakers, ubuntu-9.04

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04 and when listening to music I usually just turn the volume up and down with the buttons on my PC. Tonight however, I found out that my headphones I've had for 3 years broke (only the right speaker was working because of a short), so I open volume control and adjusted it so that it would send all sound to the right speaker.

Now whenever I play music without my headphones and try to change the volume with the buttons on my computer it does absolutely nothing. Is there a way I can reset the default values for the volume control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I ran into this article of [How to Replace the Volume Control with Pulse Audio](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Replace-the-Volume-Control-in-Ubuntu-9-04-with-the-PulseAudio-One-112786.shtml).

It worked for me, but I don't really know whether this can be a solution to your problem too, read the article anyway and see if it comes of use.

Comment: Awesome article, which also totally fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to be of help!... :)